# Unexpexted end of braces in Bibtool

Tags: bibtex, bibtool

I want to be able to search for bib entries that meet some criteria (e.g. author's name or regexp matching). I installed bibtool and tried some examples to understand how it works. I have created a mini `.bib` file:

```
@book{asar,
author = {asar},
title = {MOFS1}
}

@book{pasar,
author = {psar},
title = {MOFS2}
}
```

I want to extract the entry with title "MOFS2" so I used the following command:

`bibtool -- select{title "MOFS2"} me.bib`

and here is the output:

```
select{title
____________^
*** BibTool ERROR: Unexpected end of braces.

*** BibTool WARNING: File MOFS2} not found.

@Book{        asar,
  author    = {asar},
  title     = {MOFS1}
}

@Book{        pasar,
  author    = {psar},
  title     = {MOFS2}
}
```

I have used the syntax from the manual and I can't understand what is wrong. Also any idea about other tools like this which I can run them from command line?

Comment: Did you try with `\{` and `\}` in the command line?

Comment: @egreg I tried it but still the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the manual of bibtool with more caution, it is necessary to enclose `select{}` with single quotes (recommended for Unix shells.